# Como comparar dos arreglos de objetos en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, angular

Tengo dos objetos en javascript, el primero:

```
completos = [
        {
        "id": 83,
        "bloque": "Proyectos",
        "atributo": "fecha_cierre",
        "orden": 1,
        "visible_cv_resumido": true,
        "visible_cv_completo": true,
        "mapeo": "Fecha Cierre",
        "administrador": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 84,
        "bloque": "Proyectos",
        "atributo": "id",
        "orden": 1,
        "visible_cv_resumido": true,
        "visible_cv_completo": false,
        "mapeo": "id",
        "administrador": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 85,
        "bloque": "Proyectos",
        "atributo": "fecha_inicio",
        "orden": 1,
        "visible_cv_resumido": true,
        "visible_cv_completo": true,
        "mapeo": "Fecha Inicio",
        "administrador": 1
    },
]
```

EL segundo:

```
data = [
 {
            "id": 1,
            "fecha_inicio": "2005-02-01",
            "fecha_cierre": "2012-01-01",
            "codigo_proyecto": "",
            "nombre_proyecto": "Diferentes dentro del del Conocimiento Tradicional del Pueblo Saraguro",
            "descripcion": "",
            "tipo_proyecto": 65,
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "fecha_inicio": "2008-01-01",
            "fecha_cierre": "2012-06-30",
            "codigo_proyecto": "PROY_CBCM_0011",
            "nombre_proyecto": "PROSPECCION DE PRINCIPIOS ACTIVOS ANTICANCEROSOS DE LA FLORA DEL SUR DEL ECUADOR.",
            "descripcion": "El cancer constituye una de las principales causas de muerte, se estima que para el 2020 cerca de 13 millones de personas falleceran por esta enfermedad. Por tanto, el cancer constituye un problema de salud mundial y ocupa un lugar de importancia en lo",
            "tipo_proyecto": 65,
        }
]
```

Como puedo hacer que en base al campo `visible_cv_completo` del array completos, si ese campo es true pueda obtener la información por ejemplo `"atributo": "fecha_cierre"` del arreglo data y obtener `"fecha_cierre": "2012-01-01"` o `"atributo": "fecha_inicio"` y del arreglo data obtener `"fecha_inicio": "2005-02-01"`En el primer arreglo llamado completos tengo en el campo atributo lo que deseo obtener del arreglo data y el campo mapeo que se debe agregar al nuevo arreglo. Y obtener algo así:

```
[{'fecha_cierre': '2012-01-01', 'fecha_inicio': '2005-02-01', 'mapeo':'Fecha inicio'},
 {'fecha_cierre': '2012-06-30', 'fecha_inicio': '2008-01-01', 'mapeo':'Fecha Cierre'}]
```

No se como hacerlo. Espero me puedan ayudar. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: hay una pregunta muy similar (por no decir igual) en el lenguaje python

Comment: Primero, no encuentro una propiedad donde pueda relacionar lo que hay en _completos_ y _data_. Sin esto, no te puedo ayudar. Segundo, seria lindo si este ejemplo lo pone en JSFiddle para que uno pueda "conseguir" lo que quieres.

Comment: @drielnox  de completos se encuentra en el campo atributo, por ejemplo "atributo": "fecha_cierre" lo que quiero obtener de data que seria  "fecha_cierre": "2012-01-01" pero si el campo visible_cv_completo de completos es true por ejemplo en el primer objeto de completos si tengo esto {"atributo": "fecha_cierre", "visible_cv_completo": true } debo obtener de completos  { "fecha_cierre": "2012-01-01", "fecha_cierre": "2012-06-30",} Espero se entienda.

Comment: Creo que a lo que se refiere el compañero es cómo relacionas `completos` con `data`, es decir, lo del mapeo de la propiedad `atributo` es entendible, sin embargo hay ids diferentes en cada arreglo, ¿cómo sabes la correspondencia de cada uno?